# React Router is not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested, react-router-dom

I am trying to understand nested react router structure. I have implemented some code from a tutorial but it is not working as expected. Here is my **routes.js** file.

```
import React from "react";
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch
} from "react-router-dom";

const ROUTES = [
{ path: "/", key: "ROOT", exact: true, component: () => <h1>Log in</h1> },
{
    path: "/app",
    key: "APP",
    component: RenderRoutes,
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/app",
            key: "APP_ROOT",
            exact: true,
            component: () => <h1>App Index</h1>,
        },
        {
            path: "/app/page",
            key: "APP_PAGE",
            exact: true,
            component: () => <h1>App Page</h1>,
            },
        ],
    },
];

export default ROUTES;

function RouteWithSubRoutes(route) {
return (
    <Router
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        render={props => <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />}
    />
);
}



export function RenderRoutes(routes ) {
return (
    <Switch>
        {routes.map((route, i) => {
            return <RouteWithSubRoutes key={route.key} {...route} />;
        })}
        <Router component={() => <h1>Not Found!</h1>} />
    </Switch>
    );
}
```

I have imported

> BrowserRouter

in index.js as usual. In my App component I tried to render **RenderRoutes(ROUTES)**:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100vh", alignItems: "stretch" }}>
      <div style={{ flex: 0.3, backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2" }}>route menu</div>
      <div>
        {/* <RenderRoutes routes={ROUTES} />  This way also is not working*/}
        {RenderRoutes(ROUTES)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here I am trying to render subcomponents but the page is not showing anything except *(root menu)* text from app.js. Let me know what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: rather than using `RenderRoutes(ROUTES)`, could you switch to `<RenderRoutes routes={ROUTES} />` and see if it works?

Comment: I tried and it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The react router structure usually follows 1 Switch 1 Router and multiple Routes

```
 <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <HomePage />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/YOUR_PATH">
        <BlogPost />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
```

You are returning multiple Router in RouteWithSubRoutes change that to Route

```
function RouteWithSubRoutes(route) {
return (
    <Route
        path={route.path}
        exact={route.exact}
        render={props => <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />}
    />
);
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. It worked. One mistake "r" letter at the end changes everything

Comment: Glad i could help. If it answer your question please upvote and accept the answer. Happy coding